# How to find unsaved passwords in Firefox (if possible)

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, cookies, firefox-developer-edition

I created an account for a website, but forgot to copy and save the password I used. I don't remember it because it's a bunch of random characters. I am now logged into the site, but I won't be able to log out and in again until I know my password (of course, there is the option to change my password, but I'd rather not.) What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to find that password in the Firefox cookies or something. I'm guessing that, if I don't get logged out every time I reload the site, that's because Firefox is storing the password somewhere.

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 96.0b3 on Debian GNU/Linux Bullseye Stable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The password could be stored in a cookie as plain text. If not, see if you can change your password while still being logged in or alternatively use a "I forgot my password" to reset it.

Comment: Worth a try I suppose, although I reckon a plain text password in a cookie is highly unlikely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is possible. Unless whoever manages said website has ignored security conventions, passwords are not stored locally (in plain text or other), so you're probably best off requesting a new password.

Bit of background on how persistent logins by session cookie work here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72836/are-passwords-stored-in-the-cookie-encrypted